# Graph to visualize mean group wise and pareto chart in R language

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset which has regions of a country, states and sales in that state. I want to visualize the mean of that dataset region wise and also a pareto chart to know which state contributes more to the overall regional sales. How to do this in R language. Please help as I'm new to R

#dput for dataset

```
Region <- c('South','South','South','South','South','Central','Central','Central','North','North','North','North','East','East','East','East','West','West','West','West')
State <- c('TAMIL NADU', 'TELANGANA,'ANDHRA PRADESH','KARNATAKA,'KERALA','MADHYA PRADESH','ORISSA','CHATTISGARH','DELHI','UTTARAKHAND','HARYANA','PUNJAB','ASSAM','MIZORAM','WB','BIHAR','GUJARAT','RAJASTHAN','MAHARASHTRA','GOA')
sales <- C(89,109,92,56,43,103,26,41,126,56,64,98,26,16,61,40,61,101,191,38)
```

The dataset somewhat looks like this

| Region | State | Gdp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| South | Tamil Nadu | 89 |
| South | Telangana | 109 |
| South | Karnataka | 92 |
| South | Andhra Pradesh | 56 |
| South | Kerala | 43 |
| Central | Madhya Pradesh | 103 |
| Central | Chattisgarh | 26 |
| Central | Orissa | 41 |
| North | Delhi | 126 |
| North | Punjab | 56 |
| North | Haryana | 64 |
| North | Uttarakhand | 98 |
| East | Assam | 26 |
| East | Mizoram | 16 |
| East | West Bengal | 61 |
| East | Bihar | 40 |
| West | Gujarat | 61 |
| West | Rajasthan | 101 |
| West | Maharashtra | 191 |
| West | Goa | 38 |

Comment: Please provide us data using `dput` so we can give a more efficient help.

Comment: @MonJeanJean Updated the question. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide a desired output, so here is my guess at it..

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
# setDT(DT)  #not needed if your data is already in data.table format
# Order decreasing Gdp
setorder(DT, -Gdp)
# Data wrangling
DT[, `:=`(meanGdp_region = mean(Gdp),
          cumGdp = cumsum(Gdp)), by = Region]
DT[, State_f := factor(State, levels = State)]
# Plot
ggplot(data = DT, aes(x = State_f)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = Gdp)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = cumGdp, group = 1), color = "red") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = meanGdp_region), color = "blue") + 
  facet_wrap(~Region, nrow = 1, scales = "free_x") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(x = "")
```

[image]

**sample data used**

```
# Sample data
DT <- fread("Region     State   Gdp
South   Tamil Nadu  89
South   Telangana   109
South   Karnataka   92
South   Andhra Pradesh  56
South   Kerala  43
Central     Madhya Pradesh  103
Central     Chattisgarh     26
Central     Orissa  41
North   Delhi   126
North   Punjab  56
North   Haryana     64
North   Uttarakhand     98
East    Assam   26
East    Mizoram     16
East    West Bengal     61
East    Bihar   40
West    Gujarat     61
West    Rajasthan   101
West    Maharashtra     191
West    Goa     38")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another output guess:

```
Region <- c('South','South','South','South','South','Central','Central','Central','North','North','North','North','East','East','East','East','West','West','West','West')
State <- c('TAMIL NADU', 'TELANGANA','ANDHRA PRADESH','KARNATAKA','KERALA','MADHYA PRADESH','ORISSA','CHATTISGARH','DELHI','UTTARAKHAND','HARYANA','PUNJAB','ASSAM','MIZORAM','WB','BIHAR','GUJARAT','RAJASTHAN','MAHARASHTRA','GOA')
sales <- c(89,109,92,56,43,103,26,41,126,56,64,98,26,16,61,40,61,101,191,38)

df <- data.frame(Region, State, sales)

df2 <- df %>% 
  arrange(desc(sales)) %>% 
  mutate(State = factor(State)) %>% 
  mutate(cumulative = cumsum(sales)) %>% 
  mutate(State = fct_inorder(df$State))





ggplot(df2, aes(x=State)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=sales), fill='blue', stat="identity") +
  geom_point(aes(y=cumulative), color = rgb(0, 1, 0), pch=16, size=1) +
  geom_path(aes(y=cumulative, group=1), colour="slateblue1", lty=3, size=0.9) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.6)) +
  labs(title = "Pareto Plot", x = 'State', y = 'Count')
```

[image: Pareto curve]

Answer (score 0):

it's great that you want to explore R. I found few mistakes, these vectors will not work, you forgot to put ' in few places and you should use c instead of C (in the code I grouped by colour States in diff. way compared to previous answer - hope you can choose what works for you).

```
library(ggplot2)

Region <- c('South','South','South','South','South','Central','Central','Central','North','North','North','North','East','East','East','East','West','West','West','West')
State <- c('TAMIL NADU', 'TELANGANA','ANDHRA PRADESH','KARNATAKA','KERALA','MADHYA PRADESH','ORISSA','CHATTISGARH','DELHI','UTTARAKHAND','HARYANA','PUNJAB','ASSAM','MIZORAM','WB','BIHAR','GUJARAT','RAJASTHAN','MAHARASHTRA','GOA')
sales <- c(89,109,92,56,43,103,26,41,126,56,64,98,26,16,61,40,61,101,191,38)



myDf <- data.frame(Region, State, sales, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(myDf)

myDf <- myDf\[order(myDf$sales, decreasing=TRUE), \]
myDf$State <- factor(myDf$State , levels=myDf$State)
myDf$cumulative <- cumsum(myDf$sales)


ggplot(myDf, aes(x = State)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = sales, fill = Region), stat = "identity") +
  geom_point(aes(y = cumulative), color = rgb(0, 1, 0), pch = 16, size = 1) +
  geom_path(aes(y = cumulative, group = 1), colour = "slateblue1", lty = 3, size = 0.9) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.6)) +
  labs(title = "Pareto Plot", x = 'States', y = 'Sales')]
```

[image]